# How to use Dynamic Placeholders

Tags: mvc, dynamic-placeholder

This is my first time with Dynamic Placeholders and I am unable to find any related tutorial.

I have installed the nuget package mentioned in the Fortis Site
https://www.nuget.org/packages/DynamicPlaceholders.Mvc/
 and trying to render a component as

```
@Html.Sitecore().DynamicPlaceholder("section")
```

The component does not render on page and there are no errors.

If I just say:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("section")
```

it works fine.

Apart from installing the package, should anything else be done.

Using `Sitecore 8.2` with MVC

**EDIT**

The Fortis way seems complex. So, I have deleted the Fortis dll references and installed the package from the Marketplace. When browsing the page in preview mode, the error is

```
Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper' does not contain a definition for 'DynamicPlaceholder
and no extension method 'DynamicPlaceholder' accepting a first argument of    
type 'Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper' could be found (are you missing 
a using directive or an assembly reference?)'
```

Comment: Did you add the test component onto the page (in the xp editor) after your code had the dynamic placeholder?

Comment: Please ask a new question for the error - it is a different question to the original. Don't add new questions to your original post.

Comment: Since the edit is still there, https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/3491/288 is the question asked about that.

Comment: It seems to be late, but for additional information about Dynamic Placeholder please see the below blog post.
https://sitecore4you.com/2018/01/08/how-to-design-flexible-layout-with-dynamic-placeholder/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you have added the component to a placeholder key called `section` - with dynamic placeholders there will be an extra bit of data appended to that. Depending on the version of dynamic placeholders you have installed, that data changes.

If you have installed the [Fortis Dynamic Placeholders](http://fortis.ws/fortis-collection/dynamic-placeholders/) - this appends the guid of the unique rendering Id to the place holder, so your placeholder key would be something like `section-21ec20203aea1069a2dd08002b30309d` - the best way to use this is to add components via the Experience Editor, that way the key is automatically worked out by Sitecore.

If you have the the version from the [Sitecore Market Place](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/I/Integrated_Dynamic_Placeholders.aspx) - this uses numbers appended to the key. So the first `section` would just be called `section`, any subsequent placeholders using he same key would be `section_2`, `section_3` etc...

Your component is being hidden because with the dynamic placeholder, the key of `section` on its own does not exist.

**Update: How to add via the Content Editor**
For the Fortis implementation, to add renderings via the content editor requires you to go into the raw values of the `__Renderings` or `__Final Renderings` fields. In there will be the Xml that defines the layout. Find the rendering that contains your dynamic placeholder and then in the xml look for the `uid` of that rendering, that is the Guid that is appended.

```
<r id="{C4BD2E61-3025-4F88-9F7D-677086C576BA}" ph="header" uid="{8ED804CF-8F60-452C-A88B-4EEEB0145793}" />
```

Now when you add a rendering, append that guid to the placeholder key.

An alternative would be to add a rendering via the experience editor and then look at the placeholder key for that rendering, copy that and use it when adding more renderings.

Comment: I am using the nuget mentioned in the Fortis site. I'll try now adding from the Exp. Editor. But what about adding the controls from Content editor.

Comment: Edited to show how you _could_ do it from the content editor.

Comment: Thank you. The Fortis method seems complex, so I resorted to the marketplace package and now it throws an error.

Comment: Please ask a new question for the error - it is a different question to the original.